# using += to populate a list through while loop gives me an error

Tags: python, while-loop, append

I have a very basic understanding that `+=` and `.append` are quite similar in terms of appending new element to a list. However, I find them perform differently when I try to populate a list with random integer values through `while` loop. `append` works well, however, running my program with `+=` will give me an error :

**TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

Here is my code:

1.use +=

```
import random

random_list = []
list_length = 20

# Write code here and use a while loop to populate this list of random integers. 
i = 0
while i < 20:
    random_list += random.randint(0,10)
    i = i + 1

print random_list

**TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**
```

2.use .append

```
import random

random_list = []
list_length = 20

# Write code here and use a while loop to populate this list of random integers.
i = 0
while i < 20:
    random_list.append(random.randint(0,10))
    i = i + 1

print random_list

**[4, 7, 0, 6, 3, 0, 1, 8, 5, 10, 9, 3, 4, 6, 1, 1, 4, 0, 10, 8]**
```

Does anyone know why would this happen?

Comment: Only other iterables can be added to a list.  You need to put brackets around `random.randint(0, 10)` when you use `+=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `+=` is for appending a list to the end of another list, not for appending an item.

It is the short version of doing:

```
items = items + new_value
```

If `new_value` isn't a list this will fail because you can't use `+` to add a item to a list.

```
items = items + 5 # Error: can only add two list together
```

The solution is to make the value into a one-item long list:

```
items += [value]
```

Or to use `.append` - the preferred way to add single items to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's tricky. just add a `,` at end of `random.randint(0, 10)`

```
import random

random_list = []
list_length = 20

# Write code here and use a while loop to populate this list of random integers.
i = 0
while i < 20:

    random_list += random.randint(0, 10),
    i += 1

print random_list
```

It will print:

```
[4, 7, 7, 10, 0, 5, 10, 2, 6, 2, 6, 0, 2, 7, 5, 8, 9, 8, 0, 2]
```

You can find more [explanation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) about trailing `,`

Comment: I would include the brackets as well to indicate a single-value tuple - to maintain sanity.

Comment: @JavaNut13, yes I agree with you. this is weird pythonic thing which left me out of water for quite long.